# how to prevent the jsp to execute

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
var answer = confirm("Do you want to save?");
alert(answer);
if(answer==true){

    <%
        session.setAttribute("confirm", "true");
    %>
}else if(answer==false){
    <%
        session.setAttribute("confirm", "false");
    %>
}
```

what is wrong with my code? i made a confirm dialog. whenever i clicked the cancel button, it set the attribute of confirm into false. but when i clicked ok, it did the codes inside the true condition but it also did the jsp code inside the false condition. it ignore the condition. tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSP is executed on the server before your JavaScript runs on the browser (before it is even sent to the browser).

For the server-side execution, the JavaScript is completely ignored. It is just part of the output, just like HTML.

All the server sees is:

```
jspOut.write("var answer = ......... ");
session.setAttribute("confirm", "true");
jspOut.write("} else if .....  ");
session.setAttribute("confirm", "false");
```

As you can see, there is no conditional execution here at all.

If you want to interact with the server from JavaScript, you have to make a new request to transmit and receive data. For example using Ajax. Or by posting a form.